# How to make a template for sysout the multi-localVal

Tags: java, templates

for Example...
`

```
Object o1 = new Object();
Object o2 = new Object();
Object o3 = new Object();
```

`

I want to select these sentence and ALT + SHITFT + Z : sysout the localVal to Test
like this:
`

```
System.out.println(o1);
System.out.println(o2);
System.out.println(o3);
```

`
how can i write such a template? Thx!

Comment: Can you explain the problem again?  I'm having a hard time understanding what you are asking.

Comment: i want to write a template which can sysout all the local variable I select

Comment: like this:${line_selection}
System.out.println(${localVar}); but it just can only sysout one..and this meathod may have some problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the objects to a list and then print them all.

This is very simple, hope it can help you some.

```
public void print(List<Object> objectList)
{
  for(Object obj : objectList)
  {
      System.out.println(obj);
  }
}
```

Another way you can implement it by using **variable parameter**

code sample is as follows:

```
public void print1(Object ... objectList)
{
  for(Object obj: objectList)
  {
      System.out.println(obj);
  }
}
```

Using variable parameters, you can print objects like follows:

```
    Test t = new Test();
    Object o1 = new Object();
    Object o2 = new Object();
    Object o3 = new Object();
    t.print1(o1);
    t.print1(o1,o2);
    t.print1(o1,o2,o3
```

Comment: how can i select three line and press ALT + SHIFT + Z : and it auto add o1,o2,o3 to this print method...